# Error "no matching function for call to [...]" when calling a specialized template

Tags: c++, string, templates, template-specialization

I have a number of specialized templates which look like this:

```
template <unsigned long long>
Result<unsigned long long> strToNumber (const std::string& str)
{
    std::string cleanStr;

    //processing 'str' here...

    return strtoull(cleanStr.c_str(), NULL, 10);
}
```

When I call this function using

```
    auto idResult = Util::str::strToNumber<unsigned long long>(std::string(idFromDB["id"].GetString()));
```

I get the following error:

```
RequestManager.cpp:30:128: error: no matching function for call to ‘strToNumber(std::__cxx11::string)’
 igned long long> idResult = Util::str::strToNumber<unsigned long long>(std::string(dataFromDB["id"].GetString()));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function takes a non-type template parameter and you're passing a type when you call it.

Comment: `template <unsigned long long>` -> `template<>`

Comment: Thanks guys. I think it's time to read about template specialization again :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are trying to write is something line this:

```
#include <string>

template <typename Result>
Result strToNumber (const std::string& str)
{
    std::string cleanStr;

    //processing 'str' here...

    return std::strtoull(cleanStr.c_str(), nullptr, 10);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto idResult = strToNumber<unsigned long long>("123456789");
    return 0;
}
```

But since `std::strtoull()` returns `unsigned long long` the template form of the function could lead to problems if someone calls `strToNumber<int>("-1")`.

So that would suggest your code should be similar to:

```
#include <string>

unsigned long long strToNumber (const std::string& str)
{
    std::string cleanStr;

    //processing 'str' here...

    return std::strtoull(cleanStr.c_str(), nullptr, 10);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto idResult = strToNumber("123456789");
    return 0;
}
```

But if you really want to use the flexibility of static polymorphic code you could look at something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Result>
Result strToNumber (const std::string& str)
{
    std::string cleanStr;

    //processing 'str' here...

    constexpr bool u_long_long = std::is_same_v<unsigned long long, Result>;
    constexpr bool u_long = std::is_same_v<unsigned long, Result>;

    static_assert(u_long_long || u_long, "Requested type not supported.");

    if constexpr (u_long_long) {
        return std::strtoull(cleanStr.c_str(), nullptr, 10);
    }
    if constexpr (u_long) {
        return std::strtoul(cleanStr.c_str(), nullptr, 10);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto idResult = strToNumber<unsigned long long>("123456789");
    return 0;
}
```